# XPath and SOAP Body node replace with string

Tags: java, xml, string, xpath, soap

I'm trying to replace SOAP Body element with a string from SOAP message (SOAPMessage object) which looks like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <soap:Header>
   ..... SOAP Headers ....
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
    ... SOAP body part...
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

to

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <soap:Header>
   ..... SOAP Headers ....
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
     Body part was removed.
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

To do that I have used `XPath`

```
Document doc = convertStringToDocument(message);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String expression = "//soap:Envelope/soap:Body";
Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

// Set the node content
node.setTextContent("Body part was removed.");

TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(buffer));
String markedMessage = buffer.toString();
```

but it came back as `node = null`so it wasn't replaced with a string

Comment: Looks like you cannot use wildcard namespaces like `*:Envelope` or `*:Body`. Try using `//soap:Envelope/soap:Body` instead with a fully declared namespace.

Comment: Try to use local-name() isntead of * wildcard

Comment: `//*:Envelope/*:Body` requires XPath 2.0, defeats namespace, and is not recommended anyway (nor is `local-name()`, @dgebert).  See duplicate link for how to deal properly with namespaces in XPath 1.0

Comment: @kjhughes I have updated my question

Comment: @JackTheKnife: Did you read the material at the duplicate link?  If so, where is your call to `setNamespaceContext()` as it suggests for Java?

Comment: I have fixed it with setting up `factory.setNamespaceAware()` to `false` and then `expression = "/Envelope/Body"`

Comment: Ok, but beware of the problems of defeating namespaces, also listed in the duplicate link.